# NSubstitute and FSharp - Mocking an FSharp Function

Tags: f#, mocking

Given an interface that has a FSharp style function.

```
type IUseless =
    abstract member Listify: string -> int -> string list
```

How would you mock the function?

```
let substitute = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<IUseless>()
substitute.Listify.Returns(??? what would even go here ???)
```

I wouldn't expect to be able to mock it like a normal method, or a value that contains a function (although that's sort of what it represents).

So I'm curious if anyone has successfully mocked an FSharp function with a typical .NET mocking library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First:** yes, you can totally mock this like a normal method:

```
let substitute = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<IUseless>()
(substitute.Listify "abc" 5).Returns ["whatevs"]
```

This works, because F# compiles this definition like a normal .NET method, despite the curried syntax. This is done partly for interop and partly for performance.

**But second:** if I were you, I would rather skip the whole `NSubstitute` business altogether and use inline interface implementation instead:

```
let substitute = { new IUseless with member x.Listify a b = ["whatevs"] }
```

This is cleaner, better typechecked, and a lot faster at runtime.

Comment: Agreed on the suggestion to use inline interface implementation (which is usually called [object expressions](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/object-expressions/)). In general, when you're writing F# code, you don't usually have to jump through three dozen hoops to get your unit tests to work. Mocks, stubs, dependency injection... all of it simplifies out of the equation if you're writing pure functional code. Mark Seemann has written a lot of [good blog posts](http://blog.ploeh.dk/tags/#Unit%20Testing-ref) on the subject.

Comment: If you used `object expressions`, would you not then have to implement every member of the interface?

Comment: Yes, you would. That's one of the reasons you have to make your interfaces small. Even object-oriented people recommend doing this.